# MVC2 publish failing due to image that was removed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, publishing

I have recently tried to deploy my MVC2 application and have had great success in the past.  Now, I have removed an image that was no longer needed and I'm no longer able to publish the application.  I keep getting:

> Error 54  Copying file Images\xxx.jpg
>   to
>   obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Images\xxx.jpg
>   failed. Could not find file
>   'Images\xxx.jpg'.

How do I get rid of this error so I can publish my application again?

Comment: Can you find this file from the xxx.Publish.xml?

Comment: @Tx3: No, there is no reference to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah hah! A question I can answer!

I would make sure that any references to the file(s) in question are removed from the project.

**i.e.**
If you see any files that have an exclamation mark next to it, exclude these from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Installer? If so, that is where the reference to the image is. You can either rebuild the output of the package (delete and reset) or manually prune the reference.

Comment: I can't rebuild the output of the package as it's not compiling due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reference to it in the project file?

Unload your project (right click on the project -> Unload Project)

Edit the project (right click on the project -> Edit Project)

Search for the image name in the project XML file.